# Time Layout in Golang

Tags: go

I know we need to use the time.Time interface for dates in Go.

And to format, we need to use the format function.

http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format

But what are the valid and different formatters available for time.Time in Golang?

Comment: You can make your own or use defined constants: http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

Comment: Why don't you read the whole documentation you linked? See the paragraph http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants. And `time.Time` is **not** an interface.

Comment: Thanks Volker, will make a reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs for time.Format say http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format:

> Predefined layouts ANSIC, UnixDate, RFC3339 and others describe standard and convenient representations of the reference time. For more information about the formats and the definition of the reference time, see the documentation for ANSIC and the other constants defined by this package.

So, in the constants http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants:

> To define your own format, write down what the reference time would look like formatted your way; see the values of constants like ANSIC, StampMicro or Kitchen for examples. The model is to demonstrate what the reference time looks like so that the Format and Parse methods can apply the same transformation to a general time value.

In short: you write the reference time `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` in the format you want and pass that string to Time.Format()

As @Volker said, please read the docs and read about the difference between types and interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
  t := time.Now()
  fmt.Println(t.Format(time.Kitchen))

t := time.Now()
tf := t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05-07:00")
fmt.Println(tf)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need custom layout and/or struggling with build in layouts.

```
type Rtime struct {
    Year int
    Month int
    Day int
    Hour int
    Minute int
    Second int
    Nanosecond int
    Millisecond int
    Offset int
    OffsetString string
    Zone string
}

func (rt *Rtime) LocalNow() {
    t := time.Now()
    rt.Hour,rt.Minute,rt.Second = t.Clock()
    rt.Nanosecond = t.Nanosecond()
    rt.Millisecond = rt.Nanosecond / 1000000
    rt.Month = int(t.Month())
    rt.Day = t.Day()
    rt.Year = t.Year()
    rt.OffsetString = ""
    rt.Zone, rt.Offset = t.Local().Zone()
    if rt.Offset > 0 {
        rt.OffsetString = fmt.Sprintf("+%02d%02d",
            rt.Offset/(60*60),
            rt.Offset%(60*60)/60)
    } else {
        rt.OffsetString = fmt.Sprintf("%02d%02d",
            rt.Offset/(60*60),
            rt.Offset%(60*60)/60)
    }
}

str := fmt.Sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d %s %s  %d",
        rt.Year,rt.Month,rt.Day,rt.Hour,rt.Minute,rt.Second,
        rt.Millisecond,rt.Zone,rt.OffsetString,rt.Nanosecond)
fmt.Println(str)
```

output

```
2021-06-06 09:21:54.949 EEST +0300  949861778
```

Answer (score -1):

Golang prescribes different standards to be followed for getting valid dates.

Available in http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format